# Why does $B^{-1}(AB)B = BA = B(AB)B^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have square matrices A and B also B is invertible.
Why is $B^{-1}(AB)B$ equivalent to $B(AB)B^{-1}$ so that they're both equal to $BA$?

If I do this:

$B(AB)B^{-1} = (BA)(BB^{-1}) = BA$ 
 but for the other one I don't know how to proceed.

***Update***: The exercise I had is formulated this way. Let A and B square matrices nxn and suppose that B is invertible. Show that AB and BA are similar by finding an explicit matrix P such that $P^{-1}(AB)P = BA$

The solution provided in my notes is as follow:
Note that $B^{-1}(BA)B = AB <=> BA = B(AB)B^{-1} => P = B^{-1}$
I don't understand why this works even if you tell me that it is because B is 
invertible, I would like more details.

Comment: What exactly is your question? $B^{-1}(BA)B = (B^{-1}B)(AB) = I(AB) = AB$; and $B(AB)B^{-1}=(BA)(BB^{-1})=(BA)I = BA$. So $AB$ and $BA $are similar.

Comment: Your title also shows you’ve misunderstood the statement given. It is not that $B^{-1}(AB)B = BA$. It’s that $B^{-1}(BA)B = AB$; and *separately*, that $B(AB)B^{-1}=BA$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$  B^{-1}(BA)B =  (B^{-1}B)(AB) \tag{1} $$
by associativity of multiplication.
$$ = (I_n)(AB) \tag{2} $$
 by definition of multiplicative inverse.
$$ = AB \tag{3} $$ by definition of multiplicative identity.
Therefore, $\ AB\ $ is conjugate to $\ BA.\ $
By reversing the roles of $A$ and $B$ we can go the other way.
Explicitly, this is $$ A^{-1}(AB)A = BA \tag{4} $$
using exactly the same reasoing as before.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&7\end{bmatrix}\text{ and that }B=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$Then$$BA=\begin{bmatrix}-2&-5\\1&2\end{bmatrix}\text{, whereas }B^{-1}(AB)B=\begin{bmatrix}7&-10\\5&-7\end{bmatrix}.$$So, in general, $BA\neq B^{-1}(AB)B$.

Comment: I've updated the question to better precise what I don't understand.

Comment: I have answered the original question, have I not?